# Remove comma only in specific locations

Tags: python, regex

I have a file where is it is comma separated, but the numbers also use a comma to separate them. For example:

```
01-01-2010,a,""0.0"",c,d,""1,234,567.00"",1,2,3,4
```

where the numbers are somehow in the double quotes, or

```
01-01-2010,a,""3,123.00"",c,d,""1,234,567.00"",1,2,3,4
```

is there an easy regex, using Python's `re.sub` to remove only the comma inside the numbers? In other words, i'm looking to convert to

```
01-01-2010,a,0.0,c,d,1234567.00,1,2,3,4
01-01-2010,a,3123.00,c,d,1234567.00,1,2,3,4
```

and then finally use `.split()` to split to columns

so some ideas i tried were `re.sub('"+\d+,\d+"+', ?, s)` if `s` is the string in question but that seems like an incomplete solution.

Comment: edited @CertainPerformance

Comment: Try this regex `(?<=\"\")([\d,.]+?)(?=\"\")` and replace all the commas in group 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a pure regex solution, you can use

```
""|,(?=(?:(?!"").)*?"",)
```

and replace with the empty string.

https://regex101.com/r/LVs4sT/1

It matches either `""`, or a comma which is eventually followed by `"",`, which ensures that the comma is inside a `""<data>""` section.

```
str = '01-01-2010,a,""0.0"",c,d,""1,234,567.00"",1,2,3,4'
re.sub(r'""|,(?=(?:(?!"").)*?"",)', '', str)
```

If the `""`s can occur at the end of the string as well, then rather than matching just the comma at the end of the lookahead, use `(?=,|$)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = '01-01-2010,a,""0.0"",c,d,""1,234,567.00"",1,2,3,4'
new_data = ','.join([i.replace(',', '') for i in re.findall('(?<="")[,\d\.]+(?="")|[\w\d\-]+', s)])
```

Output:

```
'01-01-2010,a,0.0,c,d,1234567.00,1,2,3,4'
```